# Lock screen clock cut off?

Tags: lock-screens, clock, samsung-epic-4g

I have a new Samsung Epic 4G which has a clock on the top of the unlock screen. For some reason, however, most of the date gets cut off. So what I see is "Fri May." and the time. It seems like a font problem, but the phone is brand new.

I'm not even sure where to look for fixes or insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved. Unfortunately, I don't have any recollection of *how* it was resolved. Presumably a software update?

Answer (score 0):

You could download a third party customizable lock screen such as magic lock or go locker, both free.

Comment: This is alternative but not the solution.